# Texts classifications approaches

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-network, nlp

I have a set of predefined categories(like: cars, girls, etc.) and a set short texts and I need to assign one or several categories to each text. What is the best way to do this? I don't have trainings texts to make supervised learning classification.
Is Word2Vec the best choice or there is better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have labeled data, Word2vec can be one solution.

Perhaps have a look at [FastText unsupervised](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText) (recently released by Facebook) which is similar but uses character n-grams. Character n-grams helps to take into account the morphology, is more robust to typos and make it possible to compute vectors for unknown words.